# How to upgrade php in ubuntu 14.04 ?

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, php

My current version is php5.4 , I want to upgrade from 5.4 to 5.5. I'am a new to linux so Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below command on terminal to upgrade php5 package,

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```